# How do I get navigation buttons in the same line but position them differently?

Tags: css, html, nav

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: navigation buttons]

I tried using a nested unordered list but found it difficult to set 2 buttons to the left and 2 buttons to the right, I am now trying something a little different but still no success, also I want the distance between these button to stay constant when viewed on different sized displays. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(If anyone is familiar with xml you'll know that that its possible to give things a weight. so say you have 3 items in a box and you give them all a weight of 1 each items would take up a third of the space in the box, is there anything like this in html?)

This is what I have so far.

```css
#navContainer nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav1 {
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#nav2 {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="navContainer"> 
  <nav id="nav1">
    <ul>
      <li>Highscores</li>
      <li>Help</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id="nav2">
    <ul>
      <li>Signin</li>
      <li>Signup</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: "is there anything like this in html?"  [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is like that for HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Getting a lot of responses about Flexbox, i'll definitely give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

How about a flexbox approach, then you only need one list

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between; /* spreads things across the horizontal line */
}

.signin {
  margin-left: auto; /* moves this to the right */
  margin-right: 10px; /* gap between signin and signup */
}

.help {
  margin-right: auto; /* don't need this really */
  margin-left: 10px; /* gap between highscores and help */
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav1">
  <ul>
    <li class="highscores">Highscores</li>
    <li class="help">Help</li>
    <li class="signin">Signin</li>
    <li class="signup">Signup</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, the comments are extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use flexbox,

- just using  1 `ul`  removing extra markup unnecessary

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
  color: white
}

li:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Highscores</li>
  <li>Help</li>
  <li>Signin</li>
  <li>Signup</li>
</ul>
```

- just using 1 `nav` and 2 `ul`  if you want to keep  the container at a minimal state

```css
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 160px;
  background: lightblue
}

ul:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<nav id="navContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>Highscores</li>
    <li>Help</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Signin</li>
    <li>Signup</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

ul > li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 125px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: purple;
}

#navContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="navContainer"> 
  <nav id="nav1">
    <ul>
      <li>Highscores</li>
      <li>Help</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id="nav2">
    <ul>
      <li>Signin</li>
      <li>Signup</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand ur question completely, but I think this might be your solution:

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Project</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/pageFormatting.css">
          <style>
                #navContainer nav {
                 display: inline-block;
                }

                li {display:inline;margin:20px;}

                #nav1 {
                    background-color: aqua;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    display:inline-block;
                }

                #nav2 {
                    background-color: pink;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    display:inline-block;
                }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
            <div id="navContainer"> 
                <nav id="nav1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Highscores</li>
                        <li>Help</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav id="nav2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Signin</li>
                        <li>Signup</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I added  tags and the head and body tags. Within those style tags I wrote the css. nav1 is now left en nav2 is now right.

Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not quite what i am looking for. I'm trying to get everything inline. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: I just added the li in the style. Check the edit. This wil place them inline.

Comment: That's what I had before. Check the picture I've attached, it will give you a clear idea of what I am trying to do.